# чем заменять var?

Tags: java

```
public class App {
    public static void printNumbers(int firstNumber) {
        // BEGIN
        var i = firstNumber;
        while (i >= 1) {
            System.out.println(i);
            i = i - 1;
        }
        System.out.println("finished!");
        // END
    }
}
```

Я прогаю на 1.8 java, чем заменить `var`?

Comment: А в учебнике по java что пишут? Какие правила?

Comment: на `int` замени например

Comment: смотря в какой момент?

Comment: @ИванПавлов заменил на int, нигде не ругается, но код не запускается. Запускаю его с мейна, консоль открывается на пару секунд и закрывается.

Comment: тогда вопрос, что происходит в этом коде?

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко считает до 1.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html

Comment: Вы видимо под Windows работаете. Настройте среду разработки так чтобы она не закрывала окно сразу по окончании работы программы. А то так и будете вглядываться в мигающие консоли. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

Answer (score 0):

Короче меняй на `int`, а потом

```
System.out.println("Press Any Key To Continue...");
          new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```

Чтоб консоль не закрывалась